# Get Nancy Request Information

Tags: c#, sinatra, nancy

I just started looking at Nancy and I was using a Sinatra Video (what Nancy is based on) from Tekpub, to see what it could do.  One of the things demonstrated in the video was outputting the request information back to the browser (request method, request path, etc...). When I use ASP.Net Web Forms I can get to that information in the Request object, but I didn't see anything in the documentation that showed me how to do this in Nancy.  I know there is a Headers field in the Nancy.Request object, but it didn't give me all the information I was looking for.  Below is the original Sinatra Code that I want to convert to C# and Nancy:

```
class HelloWorld
     def call(env)
          out = ""
          env.keys.each {|key| out+="#{key}=#{env[key]}"}
          ["200",{"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, out]
     end
 end

 run HelloWorld.new
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
Get["/test"] = _ =>
{
    var responseThing = new
    {
        this.Request.Headers,
        this.Request.Query,
        this.Request.Form,
        this.Request.Session,
        this.Request.Method,
        this.Request.Url,
        this.Request.Path
    };

    return Response.AsJson(responseThing);
};
```

This would give you an output like:

```
{
   "Form":{

   },
   "Headers":[
      {
         "Key":"Cache-Control",
         "Value":[
            "max-age=0"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Key":"Connection",
         "Value":[
            "keep-alive"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Key":"Accept",
         "Value":[
            "text/html;q=1",
            "application/xhtml+xml;q=1",
            "application/xml;q=0.9",
            "*/*;q=0.8"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Key":"Accept-Encoding",
         "Value":[
            "gzip,deflate,sdch"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Key":"Accept-Language",
         "Value":[
            "en-US,en;q=0.8"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Key":"Host",
         "Value":[
            "localhost:2234"
         ]
      },
      {
         "Key":"User-Agent",
         "Value":[
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.29 Safari/537.36"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "Method":"GET",
   "Path":"/test",
   "Query":{
      "23423":"fweew"
   },
   "Session":[

   ],
   "Url":{
      "BasePath":null,
      "Fragment":"",
      "HostName":"localhost:2234",
      "IsSecure":false,
      "Path":"/test",
      "Port":null,
      "Query":"23423=fweew",
      "Scheme":"http",
      "SiteBase":"http://localhost:2234"
   }
}
```

You can also get the Owin Environment Variables as described in the wiki here

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-nancy-with-owin#accessing-owin-environment-variables

Comment: When I did some digging on my own using the debugger, there were a few items I didn't see that were shown in Sinatra, such as server protocol.  So I just want to make sure I am not missing something.  Maybe this is just the difference between the two frameworks, but I thought I should at least make sure before assuming anything.

Comment: Fair enough, can't say I've had a need for all that info :) I forgot to mention theres also the Owin Environment Variables.

Comment: True and it is just an exercise to recreate something being done in Sinatra, so not really that important.  Thanks.

Comment: The request url will include the protocol.

Comment: Has anyone seen that Nancy Request seems to strip out anything after a "#" symbol? so http://localhost/page#%22state%22%3A%22PA%22 in the request object just shows http://localhost/page - is there a way around this?

Comment: @dustin - fragment identifiers are client-side only. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier "its processing is exclusively client-side with no participation from the web server" - browsers do not send it to the server.